# When knowledge soundness implies soundness

Tags: security-definition, soundness

In the work of Bellare–Goldreich that defines knowledge soundness [BG92](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48071-4_28), the discussion of Section 4.5 specifically decouples knowledge soundness from soundness. That is, proving knowledge soundness for some verifier $V$ says nothing about the soundness of some pair $(P^*, V)$, for arbitrary (cheating) prover $P^*$.

However, in various works, notes, and related notions, knowledge soundness is taken to imply soundness.

In [Lin03](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-002-0143-7), arguments of knowledge are defined in Definition 9, and in the discussion below are said to directly imply soundness error at most the knowledge error.
In [GI08](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-78967-3_22), their particular notion of Witness-Extended Emulation, a more robust notion of knowledge, implies soundness.
Finally, in the notes of [Bar07](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/lec15.pdf), the definition of knowledge soundness given is said to imply a soundness error at the most the knowledge error, just as in [Lin03](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-002-0143-7).

The one thing all the above examples have in common, which also differs from [BG92](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48071-4_28), is that they restrict the class of provers $P^*$ against which knowledge soundness is proven for $V$ to at most expected polynomial time.

Intuitively, this seems like it should be the reason for knowledge soundness implying soundness, especially in light of the discussion in [Lin03](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-002-0143-7). Can anyone give a more a explicit answer about why Section 4.5 of [BG92](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48071-4_28) is not relevant in these cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that in Section 4.5, knowledge soundness (i.e., extraction) is required to hold only for every $x\in L_R$, and so there is no requirement at all for the case that $x$ is not in the language. In contrast, in Definition 9 of Lin03, the knowledge soundness (i.e., extraction) is required to hold for *all* $x$. This implies soundness since you cannot extract a witness for $x\notin L_R$, and so the verifier cannot accept in this case (except with probability of the knowledge error).

Note that this is orthogonal to the question of whether or not $P^*$ is efficient (i.e., whether it's a proof versus an argument).

Comment: I see what I overlooked, thank you for the quick repsonse!